# api.getSelectedNodes() without refering to the grid config

Tags: ag-grid

var selectedNodes = config.api.getSelectedNodes(); // works fine.

In my script the name of the config that needs attention is put into a local var, lets say:

var grid = 'config'; //so, var grid points to the grid that needs attention.

Is it possible to use the grid variable to access the api, something like:

grid.api.getSelectedNodes();

Comment: Please could you add a stackblitz or similar to describe the problem?

Comment: Hope the example below clarifies my question.
<button onclick='f_rows("foo")'>Rows</button>
Note, my grid config is var foo{} but button passes string  'foo'

function f_rows(config_name){
var selectedNodes = config_name.api.getSelectedNodes(); // This can't work because the name of config is passed to the function and not the grid config itself.
}

In part's of my scripts I only know the name of the grid config. Is there a way to access the api having only the name of the grid config, some construction like

gridconfig = get_grid_config_by_name('config name');
gridconfig.api...

Answer (score 1):

Note that `var grid = 'config';` is pointing `grid` to the string `config`.

From what I can see, you intend to have `grid` point to `config` hence, use: `var grid = config;`

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for being unclear.  I know that grid points to string 'config'. var grid = config works of course but it's not what I mend. I need var grid to be a pointer to the config. For example<button onclick='f_rows("config")'>Rows</button>, so the button starts function f_rows() passing only the name of the config and not the config itself.  function  f_rows(config_name){} receives the name of the config so of course config_name.api... won't work. I know what f_rows(config) will work, but in parts of my script I only know the name of the config.